# Authlogic: Bypass model validation if user is logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, authlogic

I'm using Authlogic. I've got an `Entry` model and there is a validation method that I want to skip if the request was made by a logged in user (anonymous users are also allowed to create entries). I assume that `UserSession.find` would not be usable from inside the `Entry` model like it is from a controller. What is the best way to handle this situation? Do I need to write a custom save method of some sort and call it programmatically from the `EntriesController`? Or is there a way to check for login state from inside a model? I'm guessing that I wouldn't want to do that anyway, since the model should be in charge of object state and not application state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a virtual attribute on `Entry` called `logged_in`.

```
attr_accessor :logged_in
```

In the controller, set `entry.logged_in` to true if the user is logged in, false if not. Then you can use that attribute in the validation method.

```
validate_on_create :my_check

def my_check
  unless self.logged_in?
    # add errors
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
valide_on_create :my_check, :unless => logged_in?
```

Comment: There is no `logged_in?` functionality inside this model.